# Contadores de histórias

Tags: debate, edição, usuarios

Me deparo alguma vezes com esta situação por aqui, principalmente com os usuários que acabaram de ingressar no site, em que eles explicam todo o contexto *social* que o problema deles envolve:

*"Meu chefe está me cobrando a 815 dias para fazer esse programa e até o momento não consegui, preciso pinta a linha dessa tabela de azul com CSS, Como faço?"*

Claro que isso é um exemplo exagerado, mas vejo algumas coisa semelhantes e com certa frequência.
Neste caso é valido fazer uma edição que exclua toda a *historinha* e mantenha apenas a parte da pergunta que importa?
Usando o exemplo acima:

*"Como pintar a linha dessa tabela de azul?"*

Pergunta que me chamou a atenção: [Interface UX em Delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288270/interface-ux-em-delphi)

Comment: Sim, totalmente válido, desde que nao desfigure a duvida. Eu mesmo faço isso, pois quanto mais texto irrelevante a duvida, mais dificil de entender o problema,.

Comment: Se é ruído pode remover sem problema.

Comment: Concordo com o rray, é ruído, somos uma comunidade perguntas e respostas e não uma comunidade de suporte técnico e ou emocional ;)

Comment: O que mais rola é: "O cliente me pediu para....".. rs

Comment: O problema é que as pessoas tem graves problemas de se expressarem, e acham que contando toooooda a história serão mais claras, quando o efeito é justamento o contrário --, sem falar nos erros ortográficos. Brasileiro não sabe escrever, e não estou falando de analfabetos, tô falando de gente "estudada", de nível médio a universitário. Enfim...

Comment: E agora sabendo qual é a pergunta, eu dei uma editada nela e aproveitei para responder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não achei o exemplo exagerado, vejo casos piores.

Sempre é possível que o contexto social seja importante, mas na maioria dos casos não é, especialmente em perguntas essencialmente práticas.

Minha posição sempre foi de cortar tudo o que não acrescenta nada à pergunta. Além dos cumprimentos e agradecimentos, pedidos de desculpa, falando que já pesquisou (a não ser que diga o que, porque não achou, coisas que ajudem entender o contexto da situação da pessoa, e não só para fazer de conta que foi o último recurso perguntar aqui e que ele precisa muito da ajuda), súplicas, assinaturas, repetição da informação que já estava em outro lugar, ou que não tem relevância para o problema, ou outras que são introdutórias para o que interessa, tipo "Gostaria de saber como faz...", vai logo no "Como faz... ?".

Isto inclui retóricas e anedotas que não ajudam a entender melhor o problema.

Obviamente que a pergunta precisa de outros contextos, peguntar só "Como pintar a linha dessa tabela de azul?" não dá para responder, mas acho que a intenção aqui não é sobre este ponto, só estou deixando claro para não haver mal entendimentos que estou sancionando que as perguntas devam ser acéfalas.

Acredito que é o melhor para o site cortar, com critério, este tipo de texto, sem esquecer que o contexto pode ajudar entender o que a pessoa realmente quer em casos mais complexos ou que ela não consegue expressar bem pela falta de conhecimento sobre o assunto.

Obviamente não podemos colocar palavras na boca da pessoa ou cortar palavras que mudem o sentido. Na dúvida, pergunte a intenção do AR.

Comment: Ah sim, eu concordo plenamente, usei um exemplo simples, mas foi apenas um exemplo
Me deparei com uma pergunta desse tipo hoje, pensei em sinaliza-la mas a questão que estava perdida no meio do texto era valida, mas achei que alterar "muito" o texto poderia mudar o significado ou algo do tipo

Comment: @Shinchila, acredito que não machucaria se você mostrasse o link da pergunta que te chamou a atenção.

Comment: @brasofilo, a pergunta que eu vi é essa, vou coloca-la no post tb: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288270/interface-ux-em-delphi

Answer (score 11):

**Excelente pergunta!**
<sub><wehatefun></sub>
Isso me lembra minha época de recruta no Exército quando meu sargento dizia *blablabla, blabla e bla!*, puxa, bons tempos :)
<sup></wehatefun></sup>

É curioso, porque até em comunidades onde a missão é *contar histórias*, o pessoal  conta histórias paralelas que não tem nada a ver com a história principal.

E, normalmente, igual que aqui, a pessoa fala da vida dela, das circunstâncias que levaram ela até tal ponto... **coisas completamente desnecessárias ao meu interesse em ler a história principal**.

Infelizmente, em outros sites não tenho a opção da edição colaborativa como na rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/). 
Mas aqui, onde temos esse privilégio, minha regra na hora de editar é:

- *"Sou novato em LINGUAGEM e blablabla e meu problema é tal"* e NÃO MOSTRA CÓDIGO, só removo o *"blablabla"*;
- agora, se a pessoa demonstra um mínimo de conhecimento e/ou mostra o código, removo o *"sou novato"* e o *"blablabla"*, pois acho que o único que interessa é ***"meu problema é"***.

Comment: Voltou direto ao meta :D

Comment: @rray, yes, é um bom lugar pra ler e contar histórias :D

Comment: Vejam, é o @brasofilo!

Comment: Vejam, é o @Bacco anunciando o brasofilo!

Comment: Vejam, sou eu anunciando o @Bacco, anunciando o brasofilo! Ok, parei... Podem apagar o comentário :).